# I am getting fatal error on line 10, what is wrong with my php code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am getting

> FATAL ERROR: syntax error on line 10

I am not familiar with associative array. I know it's a silly mistake but I can not figure out what is that.

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('','','','');
    if($conn->connect_error)die($conn->connect_error);
    $response = array();
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $encrypted_password = hash('ripemd160',$password);
    $query1 = "SELECT password FROM users where email='$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($query1);
    $temp = $result->fetch_assoc()['password'];
    if($encrypted_password == $temp)
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
            echo json_encode($response);
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$result->fetch_assoc()['password']` is not valid syntax in (older) versions of PHP.

Comment: then can you mention correct syntax. @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @UnnitMetaliya: RTFM: assign the return value of the method call to temp value, then use the array: Check [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on the official docs. The code snippet shows PHP5.4 dereferencing support _and_ what you had to write before that

Comment: Use prepared statements this is open to SQL injections. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Also you can check the password on the SQL query and take out that checking in the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Array dereferencing problem in **PHP**

```
$temp = $result->fetch_assoc()
$temp = $temp['password'];
```

### EDIT

Based on '**DarkBee**' and '**Elias Van Ootegem**' comments, Array dereferencing is supported in **PHP >= 5.4**

Comment: Also available in `5.4`

Comment: Expressions that evaluate to arrays can be dereferenced in PHP 5.4 or later [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Temp vars were already supported in PHP 4, possibly even PHP3 (never used that version, so I don't know)